# understanding vps v shared hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting, vps

I currently deploy my sites on shared hosting, it's cheap and has control panels and help etc.

I've been looking at a VPS server and understand I will have full control etc etc.

Is it easy to make a switch to VPS - do I need to install everything from scratch eg mysql, php, control panel etc. I'm a bit worried about that sort of thing.

ONe of my main reasons for changing is that I want to dip into zend and other frameworks. ON my current shared host (hostpapa) I can change the php.ini settings. Is VPS a step to far?

My sites are not over intensive

Ta

Comment: This question isn't programming related at all, so it will be closed very soon. You should ask such things on serverfault.com or any other support site for server related questions.

Comment: this question is not related to programming... use http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a managed VPS then you don't have to worry about the installation, but if it is unmanaged then you would have to worry on alot of thing, not only security but also optimization. If you're not consuming the whole b/w of your account and you don't really that much of *freedom* then you sure can stay in your shared host.